# Finding the first element in an array that matches users input and printing that location between 2 two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Using 2 two dimensional arrays representing a movie theater seating chart. Use 3 methods that take a users input asking for a seat price that searches one array then finds the first seat that comes up in the second array. My problem is that if "10" is the input which is a correct input. The seat number that is found first should be 1. Instead it finds seat 51. The problem may be with my second method which searches the pricing array and saves the location to pass to the third method.

Ive tried printing the search to see if there is a problem, it seems not to read each row and skips columns in the pricing array. Ive tried different values for where the search starts.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class MovieSeating
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
       //Seating arrangment for movie theater
       System.out.println("Seating Arrangement");
       int seat = 1;       
       int[][] seating = new int[9][10];
       for(int i = 0;i < seating.length;i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < seating[0].length;j++){
           seating[i][j] = seat;
           seat = seat + 1;
         }
       }
       for(int i = 0;i < seating.length;i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < seating[0].length;j++){
           System.out.print(seating[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println("");
       }
       
       System.out.println();
       //seat pricing array for movie theater
       System.out.println("Seat Ticket Price");
       int[][] pricing = new int[][]{
         {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
         {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
         {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
         {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
         {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
         {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
         {20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20},
         {20, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 20},
         {80, 50, 50, 80, 80, 80, 80, 50, 50, 30}
      };
       
       
       for(int i = 0;i < pricing.length;i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < pricing[0].length;j++){
           System.out.print(pricing[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
       }
       
         System.out.println();
         //Calling method 1
         pricing(pricing, seating);
       }
      
       //Method 1
       // validation and termination
       // arguments take the 2 arrays
       // Method performs user input searching for seat pricing and conducts validation
       public static void pricing(int[][] pricing, int[][] seating)
       {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         int price = 0;
         while(true){
           System.out.println("Please pick price or press Q to quit");
           if(in.hasNextInt()){                                              
  //checks to see if it is valid input 
             price = in.nextInt();                                           
  //enter price
           }else{ 
             String garbage = in.next();                                     
  //Bad input catch
             if(garbage.equals("Q") || garbage.equals("q")){                 
  //Termination method
               System.out.println("Thanks for Checking.... Good bye.");
               break;
             }
           }
           if(price == 10 || price == 20 || price == 30 || price == 40 || price == 50 || price == 80){
             //calling method 2
             available(pricing, seating, price);
           }else{         
             System.out.println("Please pick a valid price. Valid prices are $10, $20, $30, $40, $50, and $80");
           }
           price = 0;
         }                          
       }
       //Method 2
       // arguments take both arrays again and the user price input
       // searches through both arrays to determine seating arrangements
     
       public static void available(int[][] pricing, int[][] seating, int input)
       {
          
          System.out.println("Checking for availability...");               
  //If not Q it will check to see if price is found or invalid by searching array
           int check = 0;
           int arraycheck1 = 0;   //helps record location of price
           int arraycheck2 = 0;   //helps record location of price
           for(int i = 0;i < pricing.length; i++){
             for(int j = 0; j < pricing[0].length;j++){
               if(pricing[i][j] == input){             
                 arraycheck1 = i;                          
                 arraycheck2 = j;
                 pricing[i][j] = 0;   // converts that price to zero so it will represent being "sold"
                 check = 1;  
                 break;
               }
             }
           }
           int seat = seating[arraycheck1][arraycheck2];   // finds seat number with the price location
         
           //calling method 3
           confirmation(check, seat);            
           check = 0;   
         
       }
       //Method 3
       // Determines the print statement for confirmation
       public static void confirmation(int valid, int seat)
       {
          
       //If the price is not valid then it prints not found
       if(valid == 0){
       System.out.println("No seat at this price is available. Sorry!");
       }
       //if the input price was valid it prints the seat confirmation
       if(valid == 1){
         System.out.println("Your seat is Confirmed! Your seat number is " + seat + " Enjoy your movie");
       }
          
     }   
   }
```

if 10 is entered. It will say seat confirmed and your seat number is 1. If you were to enter 10 again it would say seat 2.

Comment: Try to use ArrayUtils and the method of `int indexOf(byte[] array, byte valueToFind, int startIndex)`
You can read more here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf(byte[],%20byte,%20int)

Comment: I found out my issue, when the condition is met the second for loop breaks but not the first. Is there an easy way to break from a double for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Method 2 for loop. Assign first loop "outer: for(" and add "break outer" for the break condition in the second loop.